Create secondary dependent lookup field with Graph API
I've been using the Graph API to automate some Sharepoint Online list creation and am stuck particularly with creating Sharepoint lookup columns that have dependent lookup fields as in this example where the Iso2 and Numeric_code fields are selected as secondary dependent fields creating a column in the Sharepoint UI:

Based on the documentation for lookup columns I haven't been able to piece together quite how to do this. I am assuming I first create the primary column then create a secondary column using primaryLookupColumnId to reference that column and columnName to reference another column in the target lookup list. But that doesn't seem to work -- I just get back a stand-alone lookup column that seems decoupled from the primary column I've created.
The documentation doesn't seem to illustrate how to do this nor can I find a concrete working example online.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
